# Which DTD would you prefer for mobile sites, "XHTML Mobile" or "HTML 5"?

Tags: css, xhtml, mobile-website, web-standards

Which DTD would you prefer for mobile sites, "XHTML Mobile" or "HTML 5"?

Is there any Mobile Html 5 Validator like W3C mobile OK validator for mobiles?

Should we not use Html 5 for mobile phone now because W3C not recommending it.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using "XHTML Mobile" profile. If you want to target phones different than iphone or android. It would give you wider coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what devices you need to support. If you're only targeting Webkit devices eg iPhone, Android, the newest Blackberry's and PalmOs then HTML5 is definitely the best way to go. You can then take advantage of all the cool web functionality that is supported by those devices.

But if you also need to support users on older Blackberry's and other 'feature phones' like nokia's, LG Flip-phones etc you'll need to do some device negotiation on the server and deliver a different doctype - namely [XHTML-MP profile](http://www.developershome.com/wap/xhtmlmp/xhtml_mp_tutorial.asp?page=introduction) - you may also want to give those devices an xml declaration and make sure any mark-up you send to those devices doesn't break xml conformance.

Answer (score 0):

this is definitely HTML5 because it will become the new standard (already used by the big players like google.com, twitter.com, etc.) and enhance what can be done in a web browser.

You can already validate HTML5 on http://validator.w3.org (experimental -> until HTML5 specs are released).